# Understand file descriptors and nodejs

Tags: file-descriptors, node.js

I'm having a bit of a confused time understanding what a file descriptor is and if I even need one! I am trying to spawn a process in nodejs and have its out put be written directly to an out put file.

I understand my question is specific to a language outside the scope of the unix family but I believe my problem is coming from me not understanding some thing about the system and not the language.

[This](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) is the function I am calling from my script. I assumed I could call it in such a way

```
require('child_process').spawn('./my_script.bash 1>out.txt')
```

No luck though! I know that the script is executing and that its working.

Comment: I just realized I could use require('child_process').exec('./some_file.bash 1>out') but I would still like to know how to do this with spawn. Exec keeps the process as a child process of the process.

Answer (score 5):

The spawn command returns a readable stream, so you will need to pipe that to a writable stream to do something useful.

## Piping to a file

```
// the filed module makes simplifies working with the filesystem
var filed = require('filed')
var path = require('path')
var spawn = require('spawn')
var outputPath = path.join(__dirname, 'out.txt')

// filed is smart enough to create a writable stream that we can pipe to
var writableStream = filed(outputPath)

var cmd = path.join(__dirname, 'my_script.bash')
var args = [] // you can option pass arguments to your spawned process
var child = spawn(cmd, args)

// child.stdout and child.stderr are both streams so they will emit data events
// streams can be piped to other streams
child.stdout.pipe(writableStream)
child.stderr.pipe(writableStream)

child.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('an error occurred')
  console.dir(err)
})

// code will be the exit code of your spawned process. 0 on success, a positive integer on error
child.on('close', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
  console.dir('spawned process exited with error code', code)
    return
  }
  console.dir('spawned process completed correctly at wrote to file at path', outputPath)
})
```

You will need to install the filed module to run the example above

```
npm install filed
```

---

## Piping to stdout and stderr

process.stdout and process.stderr are both writable streams so you can pipe the output of your spawned command directly to the console as well

```
var path = require('path')
var spawn = require('spawn')
var cmd = path.join(__dirname, 'my_script.bash')
var args = [] // you can option pass arguments to your spawned process
var child = spawn(cmd, args)

// child is a stream so it will emit events
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
child.stdout.pipe(process.stderr)

child.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('an error occurred')
  console.dir(err)
})

// code will be the exit code of your spawned process. 0 on success, a positive integer on error
child.on('close', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
  console.dir('spawned process exited with error code', code)
    return
  }
  console.dir('spawned process completed correctly at wrote to file at path', outputPath)
})
```